# SQLite Unique Key with a combination of two columns

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sqlite

I'm trying to make sure when I run the following query only the first `INSERT INTO` will work.. I know I have to make `slot` `UNIQUE`

The slot could be from 0-5 INTEGER but it doesn't mean that only 6 table data rows could be accepted into that table.

For each playerHash that matches it should only allow 6 table data rows as `slot` is `UNIQUE` (cannot have duplicate of same slot column, for each playerHash column).

```
//Below Query Should Pass
INSERT INTO Buying(itemId, amount, price, bought, slot, playerHash) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
//Below Query Should Fail
INSERT INTO Buying(itemId, amount, price, bought, slot, playerHash) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
//Below Query Should Pass
INSERT INTO Buying(itemId, amount, price, bought, slot, playerHash) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2);
//Below Query Should Fail
INSERT INTO Buying(itemId, amount, price, bought, slot, playerHash) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2);
//Below Query Should Pass
INSERT INTO Buying(itemId, amount, price, bought, slot, playerHash) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2);
```

Problem of course is they all pass and cause duplicate entries

Currently I use this table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Buying ( 
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    itemId     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bought     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    collected  INTEGER NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    overpaid   INTEGER NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    slot       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aborted    BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    playerHash INTEGER NOT NULL 
);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add to your ddl

```
create table ... ( ...
...,
unique(slot, player));
```

Comment: Works great now first insert passes next insert gives me. error
`Error while executing query: columns slot, playerHash are not unique`

Comment: I didn't know how to link them up in a unique way using SQLiteStudio, turns out, it has nothing to do with editing columns to unique etc.. you just had to create a Table Constraint with Type Unique then selected the checkbox's of each columns.

Comment: @SSpoke remember  to use [ insertorthrow ] instead of [insert]